# How to remove an empty key from MySQL json column

Tags: mysql, json

I have a simple MySQL table with a json field. For some reason, the json field contains an empty key which I need to remove.

What I have:

```
id  name    info
1   scott   {"": "", "key": "value"}
2   joe     {"": "", "key2": "value2"}
3   ed      {"": "", "key3": "value3"}
```

What I want:

```
id  name    info
1   scott   {"key": "value"}
2   joe     {"key2": "value2"}
3   ed      {"key3": "value3"}
```

What I tried:

```
update t1 set info = REPLACE(info, '"": "",', '');
```

which works, but only for a case where the value is empty. This, however does not work

```
update t1 set info = JSON_REMOVE(info, '$.""');
```

Sample data https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3xSRuCeqmAaRcrTUR32ARf/0

Comment: That will teach you to put valid properties on all your JSON in the first place.

Comment: Are you using MySQL 5.7? https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79643

Comment: @StackSlave - Right? Who would figure that mysql wouldn't check for valid json.

Comment: JSON standard allows empty strings as keys tho? https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf

Answer (score 0):

An option using [JSON_MERGE_PATCH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-merge-patch):

```sql
UPDATE
  `t1`
SET
  `info` =
    JSON_MERGE_PATCH(
      JSON_OBJECT(),
      JSON_SET(
        REPLACE(
          `info`, '"":', '"null":'
        ),
        '$.null',
        null
      )
    );
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sdXCz3ZmhPWr2sxjs54A9h/0).